# Весь контент изчезает при увеличении ширины экрана

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Уже 4 дня не могу разобратсья.Вопрос за которую стоит награда в 50 баллов вот [**тут**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485712/responsive-slides-disappear-on-resize)

Есть `8` блока `4` снизу `4` сверху. Слайдер начинает свою работу при ширине меньше `990` пикселей вот если не добавить ничего то он работает прекрасно но если добавить `breakpoint` чтобы указать в каком размере надо уменшить показ слайдеров то есть при ширине меньше `568` пикселей мне надо показать один слайдер а иначе два.Ну вот при добавлении этой конфигурации он работает до того момента если его ресайзить.

Если уменшить окно до указываемого (`568`пикселей) размера потом увеличить то все изчезает

Если проста удалить эту часть конфигурации то все работает нормально

```
responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 568,
                settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1
             }
        }]
```

Ссылка на [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/Onixia/pen/QrPaBP?editors=0110)

Также мой slick config полностью

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 990){
     $('.container-slick').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll:1,
          autoplay:true,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 568,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }]
        });
    }
  });
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 990){
     $('.container-slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll:1,
         // if you remove from here
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 568,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }]
            // to there everything will work but i need 1 slide in small screens and 2 in screens more than 568 pixels
        });
    }
    else{
      $(".container-slick.slick-initialized").slick("unslick");
    }
  });
```

Comment: ну пользователь сказал что в хроме у него проблема не воспроизводится ..возможно надо добавить какие то преффиксы !

Comment: I added prefixes and the situation in firefox devoloper edition is the same as in chrome

Comment: @МаксимЛенский неее.Проблема не в префиксах а в том что контент изчезает

Comment: это видеть надо ..я почитал что пишут на SO проверил ..у меня в firefox всё видно в хроме тоже и в опере во всех разрешениях экрана ...ctrl+f5 нажми может кэш мешает

Comment: @МаксимЛенский да все дело в кеше как всегда ты прав O.o отвечай на обе вопроса и забирай свои баллы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно использовать setTimeout c небольшой задержкой... Видимо из-за того, что при нажатии кнопки "развернуть на всё окно" ресайз окна происходит не сразу (из-за анимации) и как следствие из-за большого количества промежуточных значений в короткий срок происходит баг

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 990){
     $('.container-slick').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll:1,
          autoplay:true,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 568,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }]
        });
    }
  });
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 990){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.container-slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll:1,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 568,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }]
        });
      },100)

    }
    else{
    setTimeout(function(){  $(".container-slick.slick-initialized").slick("unslick"); },100)  
    }
  });
```

[ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/MaxManchak/pen/zaLeRW?editors=0110)

Comment: вот это я понимаю .Аплодисменты :)

Comment: а вопрос зачем setTimeOut можете обяснить более развернуто?

Comment: Моё предположение заключается в том, что анимация развертывания и свёртывания окна браузера длится несколько милисекунд из-за анимации самого браузера, и функция ресайза обрабатывает все размеры окна пока оно расширяется, т.е. обработка slick-slider запускается на каждый дополнительный пиксель увеличения окна в очень короткие сроки...., используя setTimeout мы дожидаемся пока закончится анимация браузера и тогда запускаем slick-slider

Comment: понял спасибо я принял ваш ответ также в анг части stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

**ctrl+f5** очистите кэш именно той страницы на которой находитесь 
и незабываем о префиксах

Comment: нет кстати проблема есть простите за ложную инфу

Comment: какая проблема ?

Comment: надо проста увеличить страницу через квадратик резко то есть сначала уменшитье до 1 го слайда потом нажмите на квадратик и увидите как все изчезает =(

Comment: какой квадратик ?

Comment: в браузере наверху есть же икс underscore и квадрат

Comment: хм....жесть ...

Comment: ну вот и это проблема не решимая =(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78095/discussion-between---and-demon-ant).